# Highchart Pie Chart not working properly with series

Tags: asp.net, angular, highcharts, pie-chart

**Sample Code**

[JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/9hgx1z60/) for below code.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [
        {
    "name": "Display",
    "y": 0.1,
    "value": 5
  },
        {
    "name": "Paid Social",
    "y": 0,
    "value": 0,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
  },
  {
    "name": "Direct",
    "y": 14.5,
    "value": 559
  },
  {
    "name": "Referral",
    "y": 2,
    "value": 77
  },
  {
    "name": "Email",
    "y": 4,
    "value": 152
  },

  {
    "name": "Other",
    "y": 0,
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Organic Search",
    "y": 23.4,
    "value": 901
  },
  {
    "name": "Meta Search",
    "y": 0.2,
    "value": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "Organic Social",
    "y": 2.4,
    "value": 93
  },
  {
    "name": "Directory",
    "y": 0.2,
    "value": 9
  },
  {
    "name": "Other Advertising",
    "y": 0.1,
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "OTA Referral Traffic",
    "y": 0.7,
    "value": 26
  },
  {
    "name": "Paid Search",
    "y": 27.8,
    "value": 1068
  },
  {
    "name": "Local",
    "y": 24.5,
    "value": 941
  }]
    }]
});
```

**Scenario**

I want to display **dataLabels** for all even y value is **zero**.

In Above code We have `"name": "Display"` **y=0.1** but still it is not displaying in Pie Chart don't know why. If any one have idea about this problem please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dataLabels` are hidden due to lack of space and overlapping. As a solution you can set: `padding: 0`

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        ...,
        dataLabels: {
            padding: 0,
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g5s27tyb/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.padding